# Wrapping inserted code from MATLAB

Tags: listings, code, wrap, matlab

I am attempting to insert a very long code that I wrote in MATLAB into my thesis document written on Overleaf. Several of the lines have long equations or comments that extend beyond the page and I would like to wrap them in Overleaf to fit everything properly.

I am using the `\include{.tex}` command to insert the code. However, I am unable to use the `\lstinputlisting` with `breaklines` command to effectively wrap the inserted code. When I use the command, it just boxes the `\include` command and doesn't even import the code.

Is there another method to force the document to wrap, or do I need to copy and paste the code inside the `\lstinputlisting` command to allow wrapping?

** Looked further into the '\1stinputlisting' formatting and found that if I used:

'\lstset{breaklines=true}'
'\begin{lstlisting}'
(copy and paste entire code here)
'\end{1stlisting}'

that it would work properly and wrap the lines. I was attempting to use '\1stinputlisting{code.tex, breaklines=true)' and other combinations but it would not work. Unsure how to do it without copy pasting entire code but this is sufficient.

Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show us an example of what the undesired behavior looks like (perhaps a screenshot)? Moreover, if you could include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), we'll be able to run your code and better help you with your problem.

Comment: `\include`  and `\lstinputlisting` both take a filename as argument and input the file, it's not possible to use both at the same time, as you have shown no code it is impossible to guess what you did, most likely you should not use `\include` which is designed for including chapters

Comment: Sorry for lack of information, I was using the 2 commands separately to see if one worked better than the other. Minimal example is
\1stinputlisting{code.tex}

Comment: You should use the `...` at end of the line syntax support by MATLAB to wrap long lines, then you don't need to worry about how to wrap the code in LaTeX. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html